# Converting a JsonObject to a list of strings

Tags: android, json, parsing, stringbuffer

So I'm trying to parse through a StringBuffer and put it into a list of strings then use listview to list out all the restaurant names, but I'm having a problem converting the StringBuffer into a JsonObject, because every time I try the getAsJsonObject(); function my app crashes can anyone help figure out why I can't cast the StringBuffer to a JsonObject and how to properly get the buffer to convert to a JSON object.
Any help is appreciated.

```
String restaurantName;
    JsonElement restaurantJSONElement;
    JsonPrimitive restaurantJSONPrimitive;


    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    // buffer is the StringBuffer read
    JsonElement parentJSONElement = parser.parse(String.valueOf(buffer));
    JsonObject parentJSONObject = parentJSONElement.getAsJsonObject();  
//this is where is crashes I assume its because it cant convert the JsonElement to a JsonObject
    JsonArray restaurantsJSONArray = (JsonArray) parentJSONObject.get("restaurants");
    List<String> restaurantnamelist1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            //get the element
            restaurantJSONElement = ((JsonObject) restaurantsJSONArray.get(i)).get("restaurant");
            //get the restaurant name
            restaurantJSONPrimitive = ((JsonObject) restaurantJSONElement.getAsJsonObject()).getAsJsonPrimitive("name");
            restaurantName = restaurantJSONPrimitive.getAsString();
            restaurantnamelist1.add(restaurantName);
        }
    }
```

and this is what the StringBuffer contains:

```
{
  "results_found": 10573,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 20,
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16795271
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16795271",
        "name": "Craigie On Main", //This is what I want to sort it by
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "853 Main St, Cambridge 02139",
          "locality": "Central Square",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3634820000",
          "longitude": "-71.0985660000",
          "zipcode": "02139",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Central Square, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "European, French",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16795271_CHAIN_bd36a0893cde3f70ab4a67f1e086d5f5.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.2",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "342"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16795271_CHAIN_bd36a0893cde3f70ab4a67f1e086d5f5.jpg",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16795271",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16798941
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16798941",
        "name": "O Ya",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "9 East St, Boston 02111",
          "locality": "Leather District",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3513170000",
          "longitude": "-71.0570370000",
          "zipcode": "02111",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Leather District, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "Japanese, Sushi",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16798941_CHAIN_d58be7a0f56ad4fbad498ba65b746a67.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.3",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "192"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16798941_CHAIN_d58be7a0f56ad4fbad498ba65b746a67.jpg?output-format=webp",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16798941",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16798079
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16798079",
        "name": "Solea Restaurant and Tapas Bar",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/solea-restaurant-and-tapas-bar-waltham?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "388 Moody St, Waltham 02453",
          "locality": "Waltham",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3695490000",
          "longitude": "-71.2370130000",
          "zipcode": "02453",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Waltham, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "Spanish, Tapas",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.2",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "303"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/solea-restaurant-and-tapas-bar-waltham/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/solea-restaurant-and-tapas-bar-waltham/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16798079",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/solea-restaurant-and-tapas-bar-waltham/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
"restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16796139
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16796139",
        "name": "Harvest",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/harvest-cambridge?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "44 Brattle St, Cambridge 02138",
          "locality": "Harvard Square",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3742680000",
          "longitude": "-71.1219960000",
          "zipcode": "02138",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Harvard Square, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "American, Breakfast",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16796139_RESTAURANT_4f9960714d6bd153a4571dd062c4ff45.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "3.9",
          "rating_text": "Good",
          "rating_color": "9ACD32",
          "votes": "190"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/harvest-cambridge/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/harvest-cambridge/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16796139_RESTAURANT_4f9960714d6bd153a4571dd062c4ff45.jpg",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16796139",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/harvest-cambridge/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it is not crashing for me. JsonArray restaurantsJSONArray is successfully getting populated. I did changed your StringBuffer though as it is not a valid json string. Check json string validity on any website like http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: The error I'm getting is: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: This error happens when the JsonElements tries to do restaurantJSONElement = ((JsonObject) restaurantsJSONArray.get(i)).get("restaurant"); don't know why I'm getting this since I never set anything to null

Comment: What did you change the StringBuffer to so it works?

Comment: Every time I try to put in a sample StringBuffer, it crashes I'm not sure what you did to make it work, could you show me what StringBuffer you used?

Comment: was not able to post string here because of its length so posted as an answer.. you can check

Answer (score 0):

If you get NPE on restaurantsJSONArray I suppose you didn't convert JsonObj to JsonArray properly as it seems the part element to object looks fine, try doing so

```
 JsonArray restaurantsJSONArray = parentJSONObject.getAsJsonArray("restaurants");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below string buffer and it is working correctly :

```
{
  "results_found": 10573,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 20,
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16795271
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16795271",
        "name": "Craigie On Main",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "853 Main St, Cambridge 02139",
          "locality": "Central Square",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3634820000",
          "longitude": "-71.0985660000",
          "zipcode": "02139",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Central Square, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "European, French",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16795271_CHAIN_bd36a0893cde3f70ab4a67f1e086d5f5.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.2",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "342"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16795271_CHAIN_bd36a0893cde3f70ab4a67f1e086d5f5.jpg",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16795271",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/craigie-on-main-cambridge/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    },
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 16798941
        },
        "apikey": "fa221c30c201daf8380ac435cedfebe9",
        "id": "16798941",
        "name": "O Ya",
        "url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "location": {
          "address": "9 East St, Boston 02111",
          "locality": "Leather District",
          "city": "Boston",
          "city_id": 289,
          "latitude": "42.3513170000",
          "longitude": "-71.0570370000",
          "zipcode": "02111",
          "country_id": 216,
          "locality_verbose": "Leather District, Boston"
        },
        "switch_to_order_menu": 0,
        "cuisines": "Japanese, Sushi",
        "average_cost_for_two": 275,
        "price_range": 4,
        "currency": "$",
        "offers": [],
        "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16798941_CHAIN_d58be7a0f56ad4fbad498ba65b746a67.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A",
        "user_rating": {
          "aggregate_rating": "4.3",
          "rating_text": "Very Good",
          "rating_color": "5BA829",
          "votes": "192"
        },
        "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop",
        "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop",
        "featured_image": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/res_imagery/16798941_CHAIN_d58be7a0f56ad4fbad498ba65b746a67.jpg?output-format=webp",
        "has_online_delivery": 0,
        "is_delivering_now": 0,
        "deeplink": "zomato://restaurant/16798941",
        "has_table_booking": 0,
        "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/boston/o-ya-boston/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
        "establishment_types": []
      }
    }]}
```